# String literal not working

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, escaping

```
String name = ...; //some method
System.out.println(name); //output \u5f20\u4f73\u73ae

String name2 = "\u5f20\u4f73\u73ae"; //looks the same as the output above
System.out.println(name2); \\output 张佳玮
```

I'm wondering why `name` and `name2` output different strings and how to make `name` has the same output as `name2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `System.out.println(name)` prints out a backslash followed by a `u` etc, then that's what's in the string... whereas in

```
String name2 = "\u5f20\u4f73\u73ae";
```

... you've got Unicode escape sequences... that's just 3 characters. If you want backslashes, you need to escape them:

```
String name2 = "\\u5f20\\u4f73\\u73ae";
```

See [JLS 3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) for more about Unicode escape sequences (which can come anywhere in the source) and [JLS 3.10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) for more about string and character literal escape sequences.

To go the other way - if you *have* a string value that starts with `\` then `u` etc, you'll have to parse it. I don't know of anything in the regular Java libraries to do this (other than going via `Properties`, which would be very bizarre), but I'm sure there are third-party libraries which would.

However, you should look at where the data has come from and whether you should really be parsing it yourself - normally text with Unicode escape sequences comes as part of JSON or something similar, in which case you should use a JSON parser.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful answer. Using a JSON parser solves my problem!